# Makefile error in Eclipse with arduino due

Tags: makefile, arduino, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to build a code on Ubuntu 12.04 using Eclipse with Arduino Due.
Every  time I am getting the error in the console as -

make all

make: *** No rule to make target `ArduinoLib5.a`, needed by `all`.  Stop.

My makefile is below : Please have a look and let me know how can I fix the error.

```
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(ASM_DEPS)),)
-include $(ASM_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(S_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(S_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
EXECUTABLES += \
USER_OBJS \

SECONDARY_FLASH += \
ArduinoLib5.hex \

SECONDARY_LIST += \
ArduinoLib5.lst \

SECONDARY_SIZE += \
ArduinoLib5.siz \


    # All Target
    all: ArduinoLib5.a

    # Tool invocations
        @echo 'No tool found that can build the extension specified with the build artifact name $@'
    USER_OBJS: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
        @echo 'Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GCC C++ Linker'
        arm-none-eabi-g++ -Wl,-Map,ArduinoLib5.map -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -g -ggdb -o "USER_OBJS" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
        @echo 'Finished building: $@'
        @echo ' '

    ArduinoLib5.hex: ArduinoLib5.a
        @echo 'Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GNU Create Flash Image'
        arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex ArduinoLib5.a  "ArduinoLib5.hex"
        @echo 'Finished building: $@'
        @echo ' '

    ArduinoLib5.lst: ArduinoLib5.a
        @echo 'Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GNU Create Listing'
        arm-none-eabi-objdump -h -S ArduinoLib5.a > "ArduinoLib5.lst"
        @echo 'Finished building: $@'
        @echo ' '

    ArduinoLib5.siz: ArduinoLib5.a
        @echo 'Invoking: ARM Sourcery Linux GNU Print Size'
        arm-none-eabi-size  --format=berkeley ArduinoLib5.a
        @echo 'Finished building: $@'
        @echo ' '

    # Other Targets
    clean:
        -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C_DEPS)$(SECONDARY_FLASH)$(CXX_DEPS)$(S_UPPER_DEPS)$(SECONDARY_LIST)$(C++_DEPS)$(SECONDARY_SIZE)$(ASM_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) ArduinoLib5.a
        -@echo ' '

    .PHONY: all clean dependents
    .SECONDARY:

    -include ../makefile.targets
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also try to use my [makefile for Arduino](http://hardwarefun.com/tutorials/compiling-arduino-sketches-using-makefile)

Answer (score 0):

you're indeed missing a rule which name is `ArduinoLib5.a:` or a ArduinoLib5.a file in current directory.

And I don't get your `all` rule. If it relies on the already existing `ArduinoLib5.a` file, it would do nothing. If it relies on a missing rule that generates `ArduinoLib5.a`, then it would not do "all" (i.e. not going through the `.hex`/`.lst`/`.siz` rules) but only that file.
Furthermore, looking at what the `all` rule does, I don't understand what `$(OBJS)`/`$(USER_OBJS)` are... but maybe they're given in env by eclipse!

Overall, your Makefile looks totally wrong to me.

Comment: Actually this is a automatically generated makefile. I am trying to build a c++ project on eclipse with Arduino Due ide 1.5.2

Comment: I can tell you for sure: your makefile is wrong, so your eclipse's build target is wrong too. Did you follow [the tutorial](Eclipse configuration for the Arduino core library) to make it work? Did you have any trouble following that tutorial? I'm not using eclipse as an IDE, there's always a more nerdy solution that I prefer (manually written makefile and vim FTW ;-) ), but for sure your configuration is wrong.